# How to get Tab Index of active/focused control on page using javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have controls on my page, is there any way I can get the tabIndex of active control or focused control?

Thanx

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that you've got jQuery, since your question is tagged ASP.NET. In that case:

```
var tabIndex = $(':focus').attr('tabIndex');
```

should do it. If the element does not have an explicitly declared `tabIndex` attribute, the `tabIndex` var will be `undefined`.